# PySpark: Transform date string to date with unusual format

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to transform a column with strings in the following format:

```
2022-07-08T14:45:04.086Z
2022-07-02T23:23:33.964Z
```

Using datetime this format works:

```
  datetime.strptime("2022-07-08T14:45:04.001Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

However, I can´t figure out a way to use pyspark.sql.fuctions.to_date [pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).
I tried something like this

```
 df.select(col("modified"),to_date(col("modified"),"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:SS.SSSS'Z'").alias("modified2")).show()
```

Without success.

Comment: were there any errors in the casting? please share that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#to_timestamp) function.

```
df = df.withColumn('modified2', F.to_timestamp('modified'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern for month and minutes looks incorrect. It should be [`MM`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html#:%7E:text=M/L-,month%2Dof%2Dyear,-month) for months, and [`mm`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html#:%7E:text=m-,minute%2Dof%2Dhour,-number(2)) for minutes.

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("2022-07-08T14:45:04.001Z",)]).toDF(['ts_str']). \
    withColumn('ts', func.to_timestamp('ts_str', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")). \
    withColumn('dt', func.to_date('ts_str', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
# |ts_str                  |ts                     |dt        |
# +------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
# |2022-07-08T14:45:04.001Z|2022-07-08 14:45:04.001|2022-07-08|
# +------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
```